# Google tagmanger is not working in incognito or private mode browsing causing chat to be non-functional

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, privacy, incognito

I can understand that because of the private browsing google tag manger or analytics NOT showing corresponding visits or action of the customer.

But what my problem is, there is online chat in our website and the chat code also put in the google tag manger. But some user they take or come to the website using incognito window or private browser they are not able to see the chat. What i have to do for that.

Here are the problems I am facing in private browser mode:

1. Chat is not showing
2. Google analytics is not detecting real time data
3. I cant see the traffic source

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I do test GA and GTM implementations almost daily and incognito does not mean by default GTM or GA is blocked.

To answer your questions:

1. I have a hard time believing this is due incognito. Is the chat
   cookie based? Than indeed the private function of your browser can
   block this.
2. Are you sure? How did you verify this? Sometimes I see people to try to see their real-time data while excluding their own IP
   addresses.
3. This can be. But does not have to be. Indeed the document.referrer is removed from the DOM when opening a link in
   incognito, but when the link contains UTM-parameters they should set
   the source to the right campaigning. Even with no referrer known.
   So, without proper campaign tracking you lose the info and thus
   everything will be marked as direct.